# Sort a string depending on the number in the substring

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a", I would need to sort it, so 
the array would look like this "Thi1s is2 3a T4est ". Number can appear anywhere in the string. I know how to sort strings alphabetically and how to sort an array of numbers, but how is it done in this case? Is there a method that helps sort it numerically ignoring letters?
I have been trying to accomplish this task for a while, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You'd need to write a function to parse the numbers out of each string, and then make them into their own full number.

Comment: How is that an array of strings? I see one string.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that each string will only have one number in it?

Comment: naomik, thanks for pointing out! I corrected that! Does it explain the issues better?

Comment: TAGraves, yes, one substring will always have only one number!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could split on spaces and `sort` based on the numeric value stored in each string:

```js
let words = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a".split(' ');
words.sort((a, b) => a.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '') - b.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''));
console.log(words.join(' '));
```

Comment: lol my answer was almost identical to yours. i give you +1 instead and remove mine.

Answer (score 2):

first define a compare function.

```
compare = function(x, y) {
  return x.match(/\d+/g)[0] - y.match(/\d+/g)[0];
}
```

then use it.

```
var z = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a";
z.split(" ").sort(compare).join(" ");
//"Thi1s is2 3a T4est"
```

Or if you prefer one line,

```
z.split(" ").sort(function(x, y){return x.match(/\d+/g)[0] - y.match(/\d+/g)[0];}).join(" ")
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment !